Quebra de linha IDLE SHELL
Estou tentanto colocar dois print's no IDLE Shell 3.10.14 em um bloco só mas não estou conseguindo.
Estou tentanto digitar:
print(12, 34)
print(56, 78)

Mas quando digito print(12 ,34) e dou Enter, aparece 12 ,34 já de imediato.
Já tentei usar um /n conforme perguntas respondidas aqui no site, mas não funcionou.

O separador de instruções em Python é o ; (ponto-e-vírgula).
Dá para usar denro do IDLE desta forma:
>>> print(1, 2); print(3, 4)
1 2
3 4 

(o >>> é o prompt do IDLE, não faz parte do comando)
Se quiser em mais de uma linha finalize a linha corrente com \  (barra invertida), que indica "continuação de linha", e pressione enter/return:
>>> print(1, 2);\
... print(3, 4)
1 2
3 4

(o ... indica que o IDLE está aguardando a continuação, isso foi provocado pela barra invertida)
Note que a barra invertida serve para continuar linha independente de ser um statement só ou vários:
>>> print(\
... 1,\
... 2)
1 2

